# Vauxhall Corsa Twinport 2004 - Issue With Passenger Door Lock

Tags: locks, door, vauxhall, corsa, central-locking

I own a Vauxhall Corsa Twinport 2004 and have been experiencing some issues with my passenger door, more specifically with the locking mechanism.

On a single press of the key fob the drivers side door unlocks as standard, with two clicks of the fob unlocking the whole car, including the passenger door, boot and fuel cap.

Whilst unlocking the whole vehicle,  the door pin on the passenger side rises as expected, but the door does not open using the internal or external handles.

Upon using the key to unlock the passenger side door I can hear something happening, but it would seem that the pin is not lifted enough or drops therefore preventing the door from opening.

Currently I have to pull the pin up at the same time as using the internal handle to open the door, which is very inconvenient, especially as one essentially cannot open my door externally which is frustrating to say the least.

I have researched the topic, however I have yet to find a definitive answer to the problem with some older forum posts suggesting a weakened door motor/actuator, loose wiring or blown fuses.

I have checked my fuses and ruled this out as the cause, so my next plan is to take off the door card.

How does one take the door card off to view the internal mechanisms. I can see that a number of torque screw need removing first but how does one specifically remove the door card so I can investigate further.

Any suggestions in relation to the problem, solution or tips would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: My usual method is to find a video on YouTube showing how to remove a panel/fascia etc.

Comment: If you are having a problem manually unlocking the door with the key and the inside handle then it's unlikely to be a problem with the electronics, instead it's going to be the mechanism itself. If this is a common problem then there's almost certainly a how-to video somewhere.